# Parse (null) sql result set value in java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm writing below native query:

```
(
    select 
        null as id,
        name as name
    from
        tableA
)
UNION ALL
(
    select
        id as id,
        name as name
    from
        tableB
)
```

It returns output as:

```
+--------+--------+
|   id   |  name  |
+--------+--------+
| (null) | Andy   |
| (null) | Jim    |
| 1      | Pam    |
| 2      | Dwight |
+--------+--------+
```

I'm passing the result of this native query in a custom DTO:

```
public class MyDto {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
}
```

From my service class I'm making call to the native query as:

```
List<MyDto> reuslts = repo.getMyResults();
```

But when I try to loop over the results, it throws null pointer exception.

```
results.foreach(rs -> {
    rs.getId(); // <-----Null pointer exception;
    rs.getName(); // <-----Null pointer exception;
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So you got 2 NPE's ?? Or you have commented out 1 line to know that both are throwning NPE ?

Comment: You have declared "reuslts" and looping over "results". Could that be an issue or is it just typo in the code pasted here itself?

Comment: @VishalSharma, it was indeed a typo. In my native query, I was fetching column as tableA_id, which was different to what was expected in the DTO interface.